# Where are the realms of a perpetual Treta Yuga mentioned as being such?

Tags: scripture, yuga, universe, treta-yuga

It kind of makes sense for Treta Yuga to be the default Yuga, as its number of legs is the average number of legs:

(4(4)+3(3)+2(2)+1(1))/(4+3+2+1) = 3

i.e., If you average the dharma in all Yugas you get the dharma in Treta Yuga as the [default yuga](https://decodehindumythology.blogspot.com/2012/04/lokas-planets-of-advanced-aliens.html).

Still, I don't know where this author is getting the realms of perpetual Treta Yuga from, so I would like a scriptural source for this idea. So does any scripture enjoin Treta Yuga as the default state of Dharma ?

Comment: What does it mean by "default" Tretâ?

Comment: Description of Plakshadvipa. As per Brahmanda Purana, Anuṣaṅga-pāda, Chapter 19 verse 24: न तत्रास्ति युगावस्था चतुर्युगकृता क्वचित्। त्रेतायुगसमः कालः सर्वदा तत्र वर्त्तते॥१९.२४॥ - There is no peculiar state of affairs as pertaining to the Yugas, conditioned by the four Yugas. **A period like Tretā yuga is perpetually present there.**

Comment: @Vivikta If you average the dharma in all Yugas you get the dharma in Treta Yuga, as I explained with the maths.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa This seems like faulty math; you factored in every Yuga into the calculation EXCEPT Treta Yuga. You should also provide units for every number to make sure that your reasoning is actually sound.

Comment: @MassEnquirer It wouldn't have made a difference if Treta is the average. You can omit as many data entries that are the average from a data set and the average will not change. You can also add as many as you like and the average will not change.

Comment: @MassEnquirer Sure including Treta Yuga is the complete way of doing it, but excluding it just saves time. You can change the equation if it bothers you.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa It looks like you are right. My other question is what do the numbers represent? What are the two fours in "4(4)?" One of them denotes the number of legs in Satya Yuga, but why would you need to have four sets of four legs?

Comment: @MassEnquirer The number of legs of dharma.  They change, but the average is the number of legs in Treta Yuga

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa From my understanding, it would make more sense to write the calculation as (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) legs/4 entries = 5/2 legs in which case the average would be 2.5 legs. The median would also be 2.5.

Comment: @MassEnquirer The Yugas last for different times. In a ratio the same as their legs.

Comment: @Archit I think this should be an actual answer, so people can see it better.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa The Average, of Expectation of a set, is dependent on scalar nature of its set's constituents. Humans, Yugas, Universe are unfortunately not. They don't fit this maths concept.

Comment: @sbharti Then why describe it in a mathematical way? Mathematics should at least be slightly relevant.

Comment: Hey only you are describing it using Means definition. I do not think anyone else described it that way, unless you have a reference? All I am saying is your assumptions are incorrect when you use Means as a statistical concept to come up with your assertion. Thank you.

Comment: @sbharti Well legs are numerical items and dharma is described with legs, so assuming mathematics at least slightly applies isn't too far of a stretch.

Comment: Maths may apply. But Means does not. Your question is  around Means, not Maths, right?

Comment: @sbharti that but mostly about realms of perpetual treta yuga