# Does Treta Yuga have a personified form like Satya, Dvapara and Kali?

Tags: yuga

Kali and Dvapara have personified forms in the Mahabharata and Satya has a personified form in the Kalki Purana, among their other appearances. Does Treta Yuga have a personified form, or does it not as it is base existence?

Related: [Where are the realms of a perpetual Treta Yuga mentioned as being such?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/where-are-the-realms-of-a-perpetual-treta-yuga-mentioned-as-being-such)